# Codeigniter function return result value

Tags: codeigniter, function

Lets say i have this code

```
$sql = "SELECT Lname,Fname FROM users WHERE username = ."$username;
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Is my syntax correct? 
Plus, do i have to declare `$result` like `$result[]` if i need multiple result values from it like above where i want to get the last name and first name of the username inputted.

Im only using this as my reference.

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE '%" . $firstname . "%'";
```

Im not sure what purpose '%" has. All i know is that when i echo something, if i were to put a value.
it would be like this

```
echo "select from user where username =".$username;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$response = $this->db
                 ->select('Lname,Fname')
                 ->where('username', $username)
                 ->from('users')
                 ->get()
                 ->result_array();
```

I'd recommend using [Active Record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html), as whats the point of the framework even with such a basic query if you aren't gonna take advantage of its features.

If you choose to ignore that, I'd say again. Read the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html).

> The `query()` function returns a database result object when "read" type
>   queries are run, which you can use to show your results. When "write"
>   type queries are run it simply returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on
>   success or failure. When retrieving data you will typically assign the
>   query to your own variable, like this:

Which would tell you, that you have a result object. So you can do `result()`, `result_array()`, etc.

Comment: If for example i call a function within the same model. do i have to return anything from that function? or is it automatic if i do this

$result = $this->function();

Comment: Well you called a function you made. How am I suppose to know what that function returns, if it returns anything at all.